# VBA: statement in if Then loop fails

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a sheet with Columns A to P.
In columns B i have customer names. Want to find rows with substring “ABC -“ and copy the content of the cell in column B to Column G on the same row.

My code fails on this:

```
For I= 1 to finalrow
    If Left(Cells(I,2).Value,5) = “ABC -“ Then
Rownumber= ActiveCell.Row
Range("B" & Rownumber).Select
Range("B" & Rownumber).Copy
        Range("G" & rownumber).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("G" & rownumber).Select
End if

Next I
```

Comment: "My code fails on this" -- what do you mean exactly? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

This one works as expected, writing the values from column "B" to column "G":

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Dim myCell As Range
            Set myCell = .Cells(i, "B")
            If Trim(Left(myCell.Value, 5)) = "ABC -" Then
                .Cells(i, "G").Value = myCell.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

- Try to avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864330/5448626
- Use `Trim()`
- Using `.` and referring the worksheet is always a  good practice
- `.Cells(i, "B")` improves readability
- `“` probably should be `"`

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Using the . does it mean, that I refer to the reference after the With statement

Comment: @sober - you are welcome. The dot means that the line refers to the With, yes. E.g. `.Cells(i, "G").Value` is absolutely equal to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "G").Value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
For I = 1 To finalrow
    With Cells(I, 2)
        If .Text Like "ABC -*" Then .Offset(0, 5) = .Value
    End With
Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For I = 1 to finalrow
    If Left(Cells(I,2).Value,5) = "ABC -" Then
       Cells(I,7).Value = Cells(I,2).Value
    End if
Next I
```